# Byobu - what do the numbers mean?

Tags: byobu

On ubuntu 14.04 LTs, when running byobu, I keep seeing strange numbers appear, such as 127 in the screenshot below:

[image]

**What does this 127 represent, and if it is nothing important, how do I get rid of it?** I don't remember seeing this in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [exit status code](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_exit_status_of_a_command) of last command.

To disable it use:

```
byobu-disable-prompt
```

More information you can find [here](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2013/09/byobu-prompt-now-includes-exit-code-of.html).

Comment: to "complete" this answer by using @enedil answer, the numbers represent "exit codes". A feature that is not in Ubuntu 12.04's byobu

Comment: @TuKsn While this answers the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html -> code 127 means 'Command not found'. It is the value exited of previous command (of course, when the value is other than 0, 0 means success).